# How is this summation simplified?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I'm taking EdX's probability class and one question asked to find the expectation of a uniform random variable (problem described here: https://youtu.be/vB6EKsX12hc).

There's one part of the calculation that I don't understand:

[image]

how does the numerator in the summation get reduced to a nice and simple `k`? Where did `b+1`go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \sum_{a+1 \le k \le b}\frac{b-k+1}{b-a+1} =\sum_{a+1 \le k+a \le b}\frac{b-(k+a)+1}{b-a+1} =\sum_{1 \le k \le b-a}\frac{b-a+1-k}{b-a+1} = \sum_{1 \le k \le b-a} (1-k/(b-a+1)) = b-a- \frac{1}{b-a+1}\sum_{1 \le k \le b-a}k$

Comment: Oh, that's nicely done.

Comment: Showing the summation bounds as an inequality makes it easier to see why you can "just subtract" `a` from `b`. Thank you and @fleablood for your help.

Comment: It also helps with showing why (n+1 -k) can be replaced with k (when bounds are  k = 1 to n) which is always the step i worry will not be understood when I'm trying to convey to a second party.  bounds as inequality may be something I should make a point of employing more often.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i=1}^a 1 = a$.  Sot there's that.

So we just need to show $\sum_{k=a + 1}^b \frac {b-k +1}{b-a - 1} = \frac{1}{b -a - 1}\sum_{k=1}^{b-a} k$.

Which is   $\sum_{k=a + 1}^b \frac {b-k +1}{b-a - 1} =\frac{1}{b -a - 1}\sum_{k=a + 1}^{b} (b - k +1) = \frac{1}{b -a - 1}\sum_{k=1}^{b-a} (b - a - k +1) =\frac{1}{b -a - 1}\sum_{k=1}^{b-a} (b - a - k +1)$

Now for every $1 \le k \le b-a$ there is a unique $i; k = b -a + 1 - i; 1 \le i \le b - a$.

So $\sum_{k=1}^{b-a} (b - a - k +1)= \sum_{i=1}^{b-a} i = \sum_{k=1}^{b-a} k$ so  $\sum_{k=a + 1}^b \frac {b-k +1}{b-a - 1} =\frac{1}{b -a - 1}\sum_{k=a + 1}^{b} (b - k +1) = \frac{1}{b -a - 1}\sum_{k=1}^{b-a} (b - a - k +1) =\frac{1}{b -a - 1}\sum_{k=1}^{b-a} k $